# Is it possible to use natural units (particle physics units) with boost?

Tags: boost

I would like to use boost to handle my units in my c++ code, and I was wondering if it was possible to use natural units? That is, can I add a mass and a momentum and set it equal to an energy without having to multiply by the necessary c's everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Boost Units may help you: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_units.html

I'm not sure it does 100% of what you're looking for, but it's as close as you're going to get right now in Boost.

Comment: So, I've been looking at that. There is si and cgs implemented. In particle physics we use a different set of units. In it, energies are in GeV. Masses are in GeV/c^2, but really just in GeV because drop the c^2. In fact, we always set c=1, and just write that energy, mass, and momentum are all the same unit (GeV). Also, length and time both have units of 1/energy by setting hbar=1.

Comment: @jazzwhiz: Then look at the "user defined types" docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_units/Examples.html#boost_units.Examples.UDTExample